# Is there a way to send a currently active apps (such as xterm or Firefox) from one $DISPLAY:x to another $DISPLAY:y?

Tags: x11

On a Linux system running X, is there a way to send a currently active apps (such as xterm or Firefox) from one **$MACHINE_A:x** to another **$MACHINE_B:y**?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out http://xpra.org/ - It's "screen" for X which does mean you can attach/detach from a running GUI - of course, the actual application will only run on the system that's hosting it and the display will be sent over your ssh connection if displaying on another machine.
The crucial feature is that it's like VNC but on a per-application basis.